# what does cusp form mean?

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-number-theory

I am not being able to understand what a cusp form is. The book i am following iwaniec kowalski analytic number theory "holomorphic modular forms" chapter . in particular what is a cusp exactly. some visulization would help.And why is it so important in number theory?

Comment: Did you try to google "cusp form"? Read Wikipedia article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cusp form is a modular form which vanishes at the cusps.

As for visualization, well... below, you'll find a rendering of the real part of the simplest cusp form of all, the modular discriminant $\Delta(q)$. Beautiful, but singularly unhelpful as far as intuition goes.

And as for the question "why are they important in number theory?", it is a very broad question. You'll have to do some reading yourself. Similar questions have been asked here before, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/325364/12507).

[image]